# Subquery causes infinite execution in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I met one SQL sentence with Subquery structure:

```
SELECT a12.ship_date     SHIP_DATE, 
       Sum(a11.qty_sold) QTY_SOLD 
FROM   order_detail a11 
       JOIN order_fact a12 
         ON ( a11.customer_id = a12.customer_id 
              AND a11.emp_id = a12.emp_id 
              AND a11.order_date = a12.order_date 
              AND a11.order_id = a12.order_id ) 
WHERE  a12.ship_date IN (SELECT DISTINCT ship_date 
                         FROM   order_fact 
                         WHERE  order_date BETWEEN (SELECT DISTINCT day_date - 1 
                                                    FROM   lu_day 
                                                    WHERE 
                                day_date = CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                           '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                           120)) AND 
                                                   (SELECT DISTINCT day_date + 1 
                                                    FROM 
                                                   lu_day 
                                                     WHERE 
                                day_date = CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                           '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                           120))) 
GROUP  BY a12.ship_date
```

It doesn't stop until I force that. But if I change where part into

```
where a12.SHIP_DATE in ('2009-09-08 00:00:00','2009-07-08 00:00:00')
```

it could be executed right.

I guess the reason is subquery contains ORDER_FACT which column in outer query also relies on it, but I don't know reason why.

I am not familiar with SQL Server, could anyone explain why that happened? Thanks.

========UPDATE=======

Thanks guys for your answer. It could be executed faster when removing unused subquery, but I still wonder where bottleneck happened in the massive subqueries.

Vote up for every answer because they are right solution, but I think it's better that some execution plan will help me learn more. Thanks.

Comment: It is probably not infinite... just long to execute. You should check the explain plan to see how the optimizer has decided to solve the query.

Comment: Could you also explain the reasoning behind those subSELECTs on lu_day. They are a bit obscure, as they seem to be handling and returning constants.

Comment: If you are hardcoding the date ('2007-01-01'), why are you selecting it in a query? You could as well do this: `WHERE order_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2006-12-31 00:00:00',120) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-02 00:00:00',120)`?

Comment: @Frazz just some customers write it, but I am not sure why that will be so long... it seems to work in concept.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this would fix it, but try to be more specific in the subquery :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ship_date 
FROM order_fact OFT 
WHERE OFT.order_date BETWEEN
    (select distinct day_date-1 
     from lu_day 
     where day_date=CONVERT(datetime, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120))
    AND 
    (SELECT DISTINCT day_date + 1 
    FROM lu_day 
    WHERE day_date = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120))
```

as this may better separate things.

Comment: You're missing the `AND` for the `BETWEEN` statement now

Comment: I just copy-pasted the code as it was, probably it was edited later on. But this shouldn't change the idea.

Comment: You're missing my point. Your code is not valid atm. The `BETWEEN` only has the first statement, so not like `BETWEEN a AND b`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JOIN instead of IN. Also I can't understand BETWEEN condition it's equivalent to constants as mentioned by @NickyW (except the case when this data not exists in `lu_day` table then it returns `NULL`).

```
SELECT a12.ship_date     SHIP_DATE, 
       Sum(a11.qty_sold) QTY_SOLD 
FROM   order_detail a11 
       JOIN order_fact a12 
         ON ( a11.customer_id = a12.customer_id 
              AND a11.emp_id = a12.emp_id 
              AND a11.order_date = a12.order_date 
              AND a11.order_id = a12.order_id ) 
        JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ship_date 
                         FROM   order_fact 
                         WHERE  order_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                           '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                           120)) - 1
                                           AND 
                                           CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                           '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                           120)) +1
              ) as SHIPDATES ON a12.ship_date =  SHIPDATES.ship_date 
GROUP  BY a12.ship_date
```

Answer (score 1):

The query is functional identical to

```
SELECT a12.ship_date     SHIP_DATE, 
       Sum(a11.qty_sold) QTY_SOLD 
FROM   order_detail a11 
       JOIN order_fact a12 
         ON ( a11.customer_id = a12.customer_id 
              AND a11.emp_id = a12.emp_id 
              AND a11.order_date = a12.order_date 
              AND a11.order_id = a12.order_id ) 
WHERE  a12.ship_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120) - 1 
                         AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120) + 1 
GROUP  BY a12.ship_date
```

as `a12` is the alias of `order_fact` so `a12.ship_date` will always be in `order_fact.ship_date` and the only way that the subqueries in the `BETWEEN` were not `CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120)` is if there is no day_date in lu_day  that is equal 2007-01-01, in that case it will become

```
WHERE  a12.ship_date BETWEEN NULL - 1 
                         AND NULL + 1
```

probably, as there will be no rows in the subqueries

**Edit**
Rereading the query maybe I was wrong, as the `WHERE` condition are on order_date

```
WHERE  a12.ship_date 
       IN (SELECT ship_date 
           FROM   order_fact 
           WHERE  order_date BETWEEN 
                             CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120) - 1 
                         AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120) + 1)
```

If I'm reading the query correctly the result will be the ship date and the sold quantity for the order that have the ship_date of the orders ordered between the day before and the day after an anchor, in that case the condition on the ship date can be dropped and the condition on the order day promoted

```
SELECT a12.ship_date     SHIP_DATE, 
       Sum(a11.qty_sold) QTY_SOLD 
FROM   order_detail a11 
       JOIN order_fact a12 
         ON ( a11.customer_id = a12.customer_id 
              AND a11.emp_id = a12.emp_id 
              AND a11.order_date = a12.order_date 
              AND a11.order_id = a12.order_id ) 
WHERE  a12.order_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120) - 1 
                          AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2007-01-01 00:00:00', 120) + 1 
GROUP  BY a12.ship_date
```

The performance of the query are tightly tied with the index and the dimension of the table, for example in the last query an index on `order_fact.order_date` will help, and an index on `customer_id, emp_id, order_date, order_id` on both table will help the `JOIN` operation.